# How to make a default item for ComboBox with a DataSource

Tags: vb.net, combobox

In my application I have a data bound `ComboBox` that looks like this:

```
Dim listaCategoria As List(Of Ccategoria) = CAD.ObterTodosC()              
cbxAlterarCg.DataSource = listaCategoria
cbxAlterarCg.DisplayMember = "nomeCategoria"
cbxAlterarCg.ValueMember = "idCategoria"
```

The class code (CAD):

```
Public Shared Function ObterTodosC() As List(Of Ccategoria)
    Dim lstTodos As List(Of Ccategoria) = New List(Of Ccategoria)
    Try
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()

            con.ConnectionString = myDAC._connectionString
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Categoria"
                con.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    Dim p As Ccategoria = New Ccategoria()
                    p.IdCategoria = dr.GetInt32(0)
                    p.NomeCategoria = dr.GetString(1)
                    lstTodos.Add(p)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return lstTodos
End Function
```

And the attributes:

```
Public Class Ccategoria
    Private _idCategoria As Integer
    Private _nomeCategoria As String
    (...)
```

My `ComboBox` displays "nomeCategoria" with the "idCategoria" value right.

Now my question, like the title says can I create a default read only item so  saying ("select your category") or something like that?

I've seen some other tutorials but none of them with `ComboBox` which are data bounded.

Comment: It's a suggestion which I wasn't sure would fit into your scope. I comment when I feel that way. Since I know you're happy with it I'll provide an aswer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add a `Ccategoria()` to `lstTodos` just under `Dim lstTodos As List(Of Ccategoria) = New List(Of Ccategoria)` like so:

```
Public Shared Function ObterTodosC() As List(Of Ccategoria)
    Dim lstTodos As List(Of Ccategoria) = New List(Of Ccategoria)

    Dim p As Ccategoria = New Ccategoria()
    p.IdCategoria = 0
    p.NomeCategoria = "select your category"
    lstTodos.Add(p)

    Try
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()

            con.ConnectionString = myDAC._connectionString
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Categoria"
                con.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    Dim p As Ccategoria = New Ccategoria()
                    p.IdCategoria = dr.GetInt32(0)
                    p.NomeCategoria = dr.GetString(1)
                    lstTodos.Add(p)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return lstTodos
End Function
```

In doing this you are simply adding to the `DataSource`. You could then look into providing validation by checking to see if `idCategoria` is 0. If it is you may want to consider showing a `MessageBox` to the user prompting them to pick a category.